# Have Django use Mutt as its email backend?

Tags: python, django, python-import, mutt

I know that you can use the `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting, and I think I have written a working mutt backend, but I can't set my `EMAIL_BACKEND` to my class because it apparently has to be the string import path, not the name of the class. The local path (`emails`) doesn't work because the current directory apparently isn't in the Python import path. And I can't use local package imports (`from . import`) because, of course, it has to be a simple string.

I got it working by copying my module into `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/`, but that's such a terrible long-term solution that it isn't even worth it.

My project directory structure is like: `django/project/app/`, with `emails.py` under `app/`, alongside `settings.py` and the others. The project/app structure didn't make a lot of sense to me (I only have one app) but I got the impression that it was the intended way to setup Django, so I did that.

It shouldn't be relevant, but BTW my mutt backend code is:

```
import subprocess
from django.core.mail.backends.base import BaseEmailBackend

class MuttBackend(BaseEmailBackend):
    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        for m in email_messages: self.send(m)
    def send(self, message):
        print(message.subject, message.from_email, message.to, message.body)
        mutt = subprocess.Popen(args = ['/usr/local/bin/mutt', *message.to,
            '-s', message.subject,
            '-e', f'set from="{message.from_email}"'],
            stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
        mutt.stdin.write(bytes(message.body, 'utf-8'))
        mutt.stdin.close()
```

How can I set `EMAIL_BACKEND` to a class without using its import path, or find another workaround? I did some googling but couldn't find anyone else who had gotten anything like this to work.

Comment: Can you specify where you wrote your `MuttBackend` (relative to the project root?)

Comment: `./` (right in the folder with `models.py`, `settings.py` and the others)

Comment: Okay, I just realized I should've put this in an edit. I edited the question to contain more info about the project dir structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The default config assumed uWSGI was running in `project/`, not `project/app/`, so the import path I needed was `app.emails.MuttBackend`.